# PHP insert if condition

Tags: php, mysql

I need to have some if conditions for some special characters. So what I basically want is to add some kind of 'if letter is oe make letter = "ø"' statement. How can I achieve this?

```
public function letter_get($letter)
    {
        $this->load->database();

        if($letter == '0-9')
        {
            $where = "formated_name LIKE '0%' OR formated_name LIKE '1%' OR formated_name LIKE '2%' 
            OR formated_name LIKE '3%' OR formated_name LIKE '4%' OR formated_name LIKE '5%' OR formated_name LIKE '6%' OR formated_name LIKE '7%' OR formated_name LIKE '8%' OR formated_name LIKE '9%' OR formated_name LIKE '#%'";
        }
        else  
        {
            $where = "formated_name LIKE '".$letter."%'";
        }

        $sql = "SELECT artist_id, formated_name FROM artists WHERE ".$where;
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $data = $query->result();

        if($data) {
            $this->response($data, 200); 
        } else {
            $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any artists with this letter!'), 404);
        }
    }
```

So can anyone help me out? That would be great!
Thanks in advance...

Comment: What problem are you getting with your code?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `str_replace()`.

Comment: You can replace all those `OR` conditions with `formated_name RLIKE '^[0-9#]'`.

Comment: @Barmar what about the `if($letter == '0-9)`-statement? Shouldnt I add the special letters (danish) like Æ,Ø,Å somehow?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the `if` statement. You just need to do use `str_replace` to replace these things with what you want.

Comment: @Barmar ok, could you give me an example? that would be really helpful...

Comment: If you don't learn to read documentation, you'll never make it in this business.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your reminder... I'm not a PHP developer

Comment: Well, if you plan on having any significant amount of PHP code on your site, you either have to become one or hire one. You can't expect to get everything done by having randoms on the Internet write your code for you for free.

Comment: What happens with words like "potatoes"? You don't want to change that to "potatøs" surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the special characters with `str_replace`:

```
$letter = str_replace(array('oe', ... more inputs),
                      array('ø', ... more replacements),
                      $letter);
```